# How to add list view with fast scroller in fragment in android

Tags: android, listview

How do I display listview with fast scroll in a fragment?
I am trying, and it displays fast scroll for listview in activity in image 1,

[image]

but for fragment it does not display correct fast scroll that is in image 2.

[image]

Fast scroll of listview in activity and fragments are different.

How can I show fast scroll of listview in fragment like image 1?

Comment: Why UI look different between fragment and activity? It looks like an older theme style in fragment.

Comment: thanks for ur response..but how can i display fast scroll like in activity in fragment..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listViewObject.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

if it's listfragment

```
getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

else if there is list view

```
listViewObject.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```